# ASP.net/jQuery: JSTree, selecting Node, can't seem to get ID

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, jstree

Currently, I'm using an AJAX Handler to populate the JSTree:

```
$(function () {
        $("#jstree").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "AJAXHandler.aspx?action=GetMenu"
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "dnd"]
        })
        .bind("move_node.jstree", function (node, ref, position, is_copy, is_prepared, skip_check) {
            console.log(node); });

  });
```

The handler actually makes a database call, loops through the menu items, creates a JSON object that is serialized, sent back, and rendered:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Select Case Request("action")
            Case "GetMenu"
                GetMasterMenu()
            Case "UpdateMenuHiearchy"
                UpdateMenuHiearchy()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetMasterMenu()
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetMenu()
        Dim nodesList As New List(Of JsTreeNode)()
        PopulateNodes(dt, nodesList)
        Dim ser As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim res As String = ser.Serialize(nodesList)
        Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Response.Write(res)
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PopulateNodes(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal nodes As List(Of JsTreeNode))

        Dim parents() As DataRow = dt.Select("PARENT_MENU_ID = 0")

        'Root Nodes
        For Each dr As DataRow In parents
            Dim node As New JsTreeNode()
            node.attributes = New Attributes()
            node.attributes.id = dr("APPLICATION_MENU_ID").ToString
            node.attributes.rel = "root" & dr("APPLICATION_MENU_ID").ToString
            node.data = New Data()
            node.data.title = dr("DESCRIPTION")
            node.state = "open"

            'Check for Children
            Dim strSQL As New StringBuilder
            With strSQL
                .Append(" SELECT * FROM APPLICATION_MENU WHERE PARENT_MENU_ID = " & dr("APPLICATION_MENU_ID") & "")
            End With

            Dim dtChildren As DataTable = DatabaseManager.Query(strSQL.ToString)
            If dtChildren.Rows.Count > 0 And dtChildren IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each drChild As DataRow In dtChildren.Rows
                    AddChildNodes(dt, dr("APPLICATION_MENU_ID"), node)
                Next
            End If
            node.attributes.mdata = "{draggable : true}"
            nodes.Add(node)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddChildNodes(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal parentID As Integer, ByVal node As JsTreeNode)
        Dim strSQL As New StringBuilder
        With strSQL
            .Append(" SELECT * FROM APPLICATION_MENU WHERE PARENT_MENU_ID = " & parentID.ToString & "")
        End With
        Dim dtChildren As DataTable = DatabaseManager.Query(strSQL.ToString)
        node.children = New List(Of JsTreeNode)()

        For Each drChild As DataRow In dtChildren.Rows
            Dim cnode As New JsTreeNode()
            cnode.attributes = New Attributes()
            cnode.attributes.id = drChild("APPLICATION_MENU_ID").ToString
            node.attributes.rel = "folder"
            cnode.data = New Data()
            cnode.data.title = drChild("DESCRIPTION")
            cnode.attributes.mdata = "{draggable : true }"

            strSQL = New StringBuilder
            With strSQL
                .Append(" SELECT * FROM APPLICATION_MENU WHERE PARENT_MENU_ID = " & drChild("APPLICATION_MENU_ID") & "")
            End With

            Dim dtChildren2 As DataTable = DatabaseManager.Query(strSQL.ToString)
            If dtChildren.Rows.Count > 0 And dtChildren IsNot Nothing Then
                AddChildNodes(dt, drChild("APPLICATION_MENU_ID"), cnode)
            End If
            node.children.Add(cnode)
        Next
    End Sub
```

The idea here is to bind the move_node to a function that will hit the handler and update the database as to where I moved the object. I've been able to create the bind to do that. The problem, however, is that I can't seem to obtain the ID. I'm setting it in the attributes in the population of the JSON object, but when I do a watch on the NODE and REF objects via console.log, the id field is empty.

What gives? Any ideas? Am I missing something vital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with it once again, I found the answer:

```
cnode.attributes
node.attributes
```

It must be name specific underneath, these must be cnode.attr and node.attr to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct-

JSTree V1+ uses the jquery bindings,etc.. Therefore you need to use the attr to obtain the objects attributes - also on a side note, IE7- are case sensitive with the node data, eg:

`$("#node").attr("id")!=$("#node").attr("ID")`